# C# 6.0 null operator in a conditional statement

Tags: c#, null, c#-6.0

From what I gathered with the new `null` operator in C# 6.0 you can do something like this:

```
string name = people.FirstOrDefault()?.FullName;
```

And this is great, but one verification I often come across is something like this:

```
object name = null;
if(name != null) {
    DoSomething();
} else {
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Given the purpose of the new `null` operator, I would like something like this should be possible:

```
if(name?) {
    DoSomething();
} else {
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

The problem here from what I understood is that when the value the `?` is checking is in fact `null`, it returns `null`, and you need a `bool` condition for the `if` statement. Since you can't directly convert a `null` to a `bool`, is there a simpler way of checking this without doing `if(name != null)` using the new `null` operator in C# 6.0?

Comment: Seriously? Typing `!= null` is not simple enough? It's clear, it's readable, the developer who looks at the code in six months can easily understand what it's doing...

Comment: What would be the purpose of such an operator? What is the benefit of writing `if(name?) ...` as opposed to `if(name!=null) `

Comment: In JS you can simply do `if(name)` and it validates for `null`, seemed to me that something close would be a nice thing and that it might be in the new update, guess not.

Comment: @ricochete there's nothing *simple* about this in Javascript - in fact inconsistent treatment of nulls it's one of the language's more problematic features. *Why* should a null value be treated as a boolean False? A missing value isn't logically the same as a False value.

Comment: Although this isn't what you asked for, do keep in mind that sometimes `??` and `?` together can give you a concise expression. Ex: `var bar = foo?.wombat ?? defaultWombat;`

Answer (score 14):

There's no point in doing this. You're not doing any null coalescing in your example - you're simply checking for null.

A better use would be if you wanted to check some member of the `name` object. For example:

```
if (name?.FirstName != null) ...
```

But as you can see, it's still a simple comparison for null - we just used null coalescing to avoid having to write something like this:

```
if (name != null && name.FirstName != null) ...
```

Comment: I agree that it wouldn't be the better use of this feature, however I was going for something much simpler, something of the likes `if(name)` in JS, where it validates automatically for `null`. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I like to do something like:    if (Session?.Connected) { } but unfortunately this is not supported and you have to do something like: if (Session?.Connected == true) {}

Comment: @juFo That's kind of obvious, if you think about it - since you're using the coalescing operator, the `bool` is turned into `bool?` (the `null` has to propagate through all the null coalesces). And `if (default(bool?))` makes exactly as much sense as allowing `if (null)` - which is to say, not a whole lot. What you *can* do is use `(session?.Connected).GetValueOrDefault(false)` - which is a lot more explicit than just `a == true`.

Comment: @Luaan or more concisely `if (session?.Connected ?? false)` - which still isn't any shorter or clearer than what juFo did. Starts to be more useful when more alernatives are wanted : `if(session?.Connected ?? RestartSession()?.Connected ?? false)`